# android AOSP, adding new executable [.c] code

Tags: android

I have been trying to introduce new command in the android build.

**What i Did:**

In In AOSP Source Tree:

1) In android/External Directory create new Directory Say: 
    newCmd/newCmd.c, newCmd/Android.mk

```
In the Android.mk

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= newCmd.c
LOCAL_MODULE := newCmd
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcutils libc
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

2) at Top, i ran 'm' command. 
     My program got compiled, and got below output.

```
target Executable: newCmd (out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/newCmd_intermediates/LINKED/newCmd)
target Symbolic: newCmd (out/target/product/generic/symbols/system/bin/newCmd)
Export includes file: external/newCmd/Android.mk -- out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/newCmd_intermediates/export_includes
target Strip: newCmd (out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/newCmd_intermediates/newCmd)
Target ram disk: out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img
```

**QUESTION:**

When i launch emulator, i dont see the newCmd in the /system/bin directory.

Did i miss anything?

Kindly Advice.

Answer (score 4):

Ok.

I found the solution. it hast got resolved, after i include the package name  in the core.mk file under PRODUCT_PACKAGES tag.

Anyhow thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you place your code in a wrong place, the external folder is not used for implementing commands that would be used inside the android system.

Move your newCmd folder into framework/base/cmds, and add the module name of your new command(say newCmd) into build/target/product/base.mk