# Adding the tests directory to the android build system.img

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I need to add the timetest directory's executable to the system.img file so that I can access the command from the shell. The location is at : https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/android-4.4.4_r1/tests/timetest/. So what I did was to go into the timetest directory and issue the following command:

```
mm snod
```

The output was as follows:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/generic/goldfish/data/etc/apns-conf.xml:system/etc/apns-conf.xml ignored.
make: Entering directory `/home/username/android_built/android'
target thumb C: timetest <= frameworks/base/cmds/timetest/timetest.c
target StaticExecutable: timetest (out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/timetest_intermediates/LINKED/timetest)
target Symbolic: timetest (out/target/product/hammerhead/symbols/sbin/timetest)
target Strip: timetest (out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/timetest_intermediates/timetest)
Install: out/target/product/hammerhead/root/sbin/timetest
make: Leaving directory `/home/username/android_built/android'
```

The file installation part has been left out for clarity.

The following output is after I tried copying the timetest into frameworks/base/cmds as detailed in this question : [android AOSP, adding new executable [.c] code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899360/android-aosp-adding-new-executable-c-code). I also tried it directly.

I then looked at the entire phone including the xbin,bin directories . I also used find / -name "timetest", but the executable is nowhere to be found. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually sure how you are installing timetest to your device, but if you are just adb pushing the result to your device then you will likely have a hard time running that.

If you look at the Android.mk file for timetest you will see that it is labeled as "optional"

```
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
```

However after grepping through all the make files, there is no build variant which includes this in a build. If you have your own device make file you can add it there, but if you just want to make this work quickly you can add it to the list of PRODUCT_PACKAGES in the build/target/product/core_minimal.mk file. There will be a list that looks something like:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    BackupRestoreConfirmation \
    DownloadProvider \
    HTMLViewer \
    MediaProvider \
```

Just add timetest into that list. After that do a make installclean and rebuild your device and you should have timetest included in sbin.